# Add multiple in-app products to Android app via own system/api

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have to develop an android app for a client. The client wants to sell ebooks through his app, other people should be able to add their ebooks to the app. Is it possible to add in-app products to the Google Play developer console via my own system or via an API?

I know you can add a batch of products by uploading a CSV file to the developer console but I want to be able to let other people add in-app products via my site.